# Anyone knows why setCount() is not working in twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter4j

Hello i am trying to Just retrieve 1 tweet using Twitter4j but the setCount() method is doing what ever it wants ( maybe its just me doing something wrong ) i leave my code below. 
I have tried with multiple options "1", "2","0" and regardless the number it retrieves any amount of tweets from 3 to 10.

```
 ConfigurationBuilder cf = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    cf.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxx")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxx")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("xxxx")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxx");

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cf.build());
    twitter4j.Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    try {
        Query query = new Query("sverige");
        QueryResult result;
        do {

            query.setCount(2);
            result = twitter.search(query);
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
            for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + tweet.getFavoriteCount() + tweet.getUser().getName());
            }
        } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: does result.nextQuery() trigger a new search?

Comment: If you elaborate your answer in a nice manner i will vote you up. I have no idea why i didnt see it. and yes you are right.

Comment: I wasn't being sarcastic, I was just asking because I wasn't sure :)

Comment: I know dont worry i mean make a "Formal Answer" so i can vote it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop will continue to query for tweets while more tweets are available.
This is because 
`(query = result.nextQuery()) != null` is true until all of the tweets (matching the query) are read.
`setCount` only limits the amount of tweets each search operation returns.

WHen debugging a situation like this (if you don't want to look into the source code / documentation) you can test how many times the outer loop occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting all the tweets from that user, at 2 results per page. So if they had 22 tweets, you would get 11 pages of 2 tweets per page.

```
query.setCount(2); // set the number of tweets per page

// get the next page until there are no more pages 
} while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
```